# How to find several types of files in Linux shell?

Tags: linux

When I try to find `.c` file, I can use below command:

```
find . -name *.c
```

As for `.h` file:

```
find . -name *h
```

Then how to find them at the same time? I know one solution:

```
find . -namd *.c && find . -name *.h
```

Is there any better answer?

**Further**:
In fact I need to find .c .h .p .hpp .cpp .p files. Then how to do?

```
find . -name '*.[chcpphppp]'
```

Above one seems not right?

Comment: you really should read the documentation of `find`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do

```
find . -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h'
```

or better

```
find . -name '*.[ch]'
```

but you really should read the documentation of `find`

Comment: I need to find .c .cpp .h .hpp .p files. Then how to find them? find . -name '*.[chcpphppp]'??

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
find . -name "*.[ch]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (`-o` is "OR"):

```
find . -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h'
```

or

```
find . -name '*.[hc]'
```